# Tinymce editor image upload plugin add full image URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using an image uploader plugin called justboil.com for tinymce editor.

It word great, and uploads images to display them but i want it to be able to add the full web URL to the path of the image like:

*http://www.domain.com/upload_img/img1.jpg*

rather than

*/upload_img/img1.jpg*

here is the config code for the plugin

```
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Path to upload target folder, relative to domain name. NO TRAILING SLASH!
| Example: if an image is acessed via http://www.example.com/images/somefolder/image.jpg, you should specify here:
| 
| $config['img_path'] = '/images/somefolder';
| 
| -------------------------------------------------------------------*/


    $config['img_path'] = '/upload_img'; // Relative to domain name

    $config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path. [Usually works fine like this]
```

i have tried changing the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to the full domain name but it doesn't upload the images if i do that

any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside your tinymce init, you can set the following tags:

```
relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false
```

This will then enable absolute urls with the full address for all items added in the TinyMCE editor.

Comment: This fix still works as of 2023, v6 of TinyMCE.