# TinyMCE Editor adds data-mce-src to <img />

Tags: html, tinymce

I'm using the TinyMCE 4.0.11 and it seems there is a Problem with the TinyMCE, because it adds a "data-mce-src" attribute to the img tag, which overwrites the "src" attribute. If i add an image with src attribute set to "http://example.com/img.jpg", the data-mce-src attribute contains "/http://example.com/img.jpg" with the "/" at the beginning. How can i prevent the tinymce adding the data-mce-src attribute?

I tried the following options for the TinyMCE configuration:

- relative_urls: false,
- inline: false,
- content_css: false,
- convert_urls: false

Nothing fixed the problem.

Comment: How you get the result after saving? I think the `mce-*` attributes are only for handling. Have you an smart example?

Answer (score 18):

This question solved this issue for me with tinymce 4

[Tinymce editor image upload plugin add full image URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858179/tinymce-editor-image-upload-plugin-add-full-image-url)

```
    relative_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false
```